# Bootstrap nav vertical align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

How can I align text in Bootstrap nav... I have this html code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-justified">

    <li><a href="#">PREVIOUS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick = "myFunction();">PLAY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick = "stop();">PAUSE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">NEXT</a></li>

</ul>
```

This PREVIOUS, PLAY, PAUSE and NEXT text needs to be aligned top.

Comment: Aligned top..? is that it..> top  of what?  how does your page looks like now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use custom styles, by default `.nav` has a padding, so if you reset the top padding to 0 it'll be aligned as you want.... try this

```
.nav > li > a {
   padding-top: 0;
}
```

**EDIT** make sure you use it AFTER you include `bootstrap.css` in your project

Comment: what do you mean it does not work? by removing the top padding, you align the text to the top of the `.nav`. Or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: padding-top: 0; did the trick... It was only not updating for some reason... Thank you